# Как подключить шейдеры в WebGL-приложениях?

Tags: javascript, html5, графика, webgl, glsl

В книге К. Мацуда, Р. Ли - WebGL. Программирование трехмерной графики везде используется встроенные шейдеры. Как подключить шейдеры из файлов. Решение описанное в этой же книге не заработало:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/Development/WebGL/DrawPoint/DrawPointVertesShader.gls. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.loadShaderFile @ ShaderUtilities.js:12
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/Development/WebGL/DrawPoint/DrawPointFragmentShader.gls. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Некоторые предлагали поднимать сервак и оттуда брать. Но это не годится так как пишется игра и конечно игра должна работать без сучка и задоринок у пользователя. Есть ли какой-нибудь простой механизм?

Comment: Поднимать сервер. Есть хостинги для статики, тот же [Github Pages](http://pages.github.com).

Answer (score 4):

Истоки Вашей проблемы в том, что с веб страниц, которые были открыты по протоколу `file://` **не удается** получить по этому-же протоколу ресурсы, которые лежат рядом на диске. Эта возможность в браузерах отключена из соображений безопасности.

---

Однако, Вы совершенно **не обязаны** подключать шейдеры как отдельные файлы.

Вам необходимо лишь передать компилятору шейдеров их исходный код, в виде строк, а как вы будете хранить и получать эти строки в том месте где она нужны - дело десятое.

---

Таким образом Вы можете создать одну **html страницу с webgl приложением**, которое будет открываться локально и **без веб-сервера**.

> Можно держать **glsl** код прямо в **javascript** секциях в виде строк:

```html
<canvas>
<script>
  let started = new Date().getTime();
  let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  let size = canvas.width = canvas.height = 150;
  let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
  let pid = gl.createProgram();
  
  shader(`
    attribute vec2 coords;
      void main(void) {
      gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
  `, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

  shader(`
    precision highp float;
    uniform float time;
    void main(void) {
      vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / ${size}.;
      gl_FragColor = vec4(uv,sin(time),1.);
    }
  `, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

  gl.linkProgram(pid);
  gl.useProgram(pid);

  let array = new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2 /*components per vertex */, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);

  let time = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');

  draw();

  function draw() {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    gl.uniform1f(time, (new Date().getTime() - started)/1000);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, size, size);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  }

  function shader(src, type) {
    let sid = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
    gl.compileShader(sid);
    gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  }
</script>
```

---

Если используется любой любой из всевозможных современных бандлеров(вроде webpack), которые упаковывают веб приложения в одну или несколько портянок js, вы можете держать текст шейдера в отдельном файле. И импортировать его по месту использования, так появляется какая никакая **модульность в glsl**.

Следующим шагом является модульность непосредственно внутри **glsl** кода, (чтобы не копи-пастить по 300 раз в разных шейдерах один и тот же код) тут 2 пути: 
собственный велосипед или более серьезное решение, например вот [glslify](https://github.com/glslify/glslify) это уже готовое решение и огромная [экосистема](http://stack.gl/) всевозможных кусочков для шейдеров, построенная поверх **npm**

```
let glsl = require('glslify')

let shaderCode = glsl(`
  #pragma glslify: noise = require('glsl-noise/simplex/3d')
  precision mediump float;
  varying vec3 vpos;
  void main () {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(noise(vpos*25.0),1);
  }
`);
```

---

> На просторах интернета и во многих туториалах используют теги `<script>`  с отличным от `text/javascript` типом. Косвенно используя то, что такие секции не будут автоматически выполнятся сами, как собственно **javascript**:

Вот пример:

```html
<canvas></canvas>

<script type='glsl/vertex'>
  attribute vec2 coords;
  void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
</script>

<script type='glsl/fragment'>precision highp float;
   uniform vec4 mr; // (m)ouse position and screen (r)esolution
   void main(void) {
     vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy;
     vec2 q = (p + p - mr.ba) / mr.b;
     for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) 
          q = abs(q)/dot(q,q) -  mr.xy/mr.zw;
     gl_FragColor = vec4(q, q.x/q.y, 1.0);
   }
</script>

<script>
  let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
  var h = gl.drawingBufferHeight;
  var w = gl.drawingBufferWidth;
  
  let pid = gl.createProgram();
  shader('glsl/vertex', gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  shader('glsl/fragment', gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.linkProgram(pid);
  gl.useProgram(pid);

  let array = new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2 /*components per vertex */, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);
  
  let mr = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'mr');  // (m)ouse position and screen (r)esolution
  
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
  window.addEventListener('touchmove', draw);

  draw();

  function draw(e) {
    let ev = e && e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;
    let x = ev ? ev.clientX : 250;
    let y = ev ? h - ev.clientY: 111;
    gl.uniform4f(mr, x, y, w, h);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3 /* 3 vertices */); 
  }

  function shader(name, type) {
    let src = [...document.scripts].find(s => s.type === name).innerText;
    let sid = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
    gl.compileShader(sid);
    gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  }
</script>

<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>
```

PS: фрактал, который тут рисуется нашел и рассказал о нем миру некто `Kali` в этом топике с [`fractalforums`](http://www.fractalforums.com/new-theories-and-research/very-simple-formula-for-fractal-patterns/)

Comment: Да уж. Отличный ответ и картинка завораживает и не одной поклёвки. Совсем народ заелся :))

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо за доброе слово, а картинка это фрактал Kali(https://twitter.com/pabloandrioli), с небольшим изменением

Comment: @Alexandr_TT поменял число итераций, в шейдере, теперь интереснее картинка

Comment: Вообще блеск стало. Ладно, до завтра